# double pointer and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

I don't understand why printing pp where pp is a double pointer to p returns adress of p while printing p returns a but p is a pointer to a. In general I don't get why printing pp doesnt return the adress of the pp pointer. the code looks the following:

```
int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *p[] = {a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4 }; 
int **pp = p;

main() {
printf(“...”, p, *p, **p); 
printf(“...”, pp, *pp, **pp); }

//and when i print it looks like this:

p = address of p 
*p = address of a 
**p = 0


pp = address of p 
*pp = address of a
**pp = 0
```

Comment: For any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is exactly the same as `*(a + i)`. From that can be deduced that `a + i` is a pointer to the i:th element, and also that `*a` is the same as `a[0]`. So `*p` is the same as `p[0]`, and `**p` is the same as `p[0][0]`.

Comment: `main()` without `int`? It looks like your C textbook is outdated by some 30 years.

Comment: Also note that array to pointer decay means that plain `p` is the same as `&p[0]`. So `p` is *not* the "address of p" as stated in your question. The "address of p" would be `&p`.

Comment: And I also recommend, whenever you have problem with pointers, use pen and paper to draw it all out. Draw a long rectangle, and divide it into five pieces, label every piece `a[0]`, `a[1]` etc. Then draw a similar box with five elements, for `p`. But besides labeling the elements of `p`, also draw arrows from each element of `p` to the corresponding element of `a`. Finally draw a small box, labeled `pp`, and draw a single arrow to `p[0]`. That's how all the pointers in your example are set up.

Comment: but what does printing pp then actually mean like I still don't get why I then get the same result as when I print p?

Comment: Well you wrote `pp = p` so why do you expect p and pp be different?

Answer (score 1):

> p is a pointer to a

`p` is an array. It is not a pointer.

`int *p[] = {a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4 };` declares `p` to be an array of pointers to `int` and initializes the elements of `p` to the addresses of `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]`, and `a[4]`.

In `int **pp = p;`, the array `p` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. This is a rule in C: When an array is used in an expression and is not the operand of `sizeof`, is not the operand of unary `&`, and is not a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So `p` is converted to `&p[0]`. So the declaration is equivalent to `int **pp = &p[0];`, which sets `pp` to point to the first element of `p`.

In `printf(“...”, p, *p, **p);`:

- `p` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so `&p[0]` is sent to `printf`. (Also note that the start of an array and the start of its first element are at the same place, so `&p` and `&p[0]` are the same address, albeit of different types.)
- `*p` is the first element of `p`. (In detail, `p` is converted to a pointer to its first element, `&p[0]`, so `*p` is `*&p[0]`, which is `p[0]`. Then the value of that element is sent to `printf`. (Technically, there is another conversion here; `p[0]` is an lvalue for the first element of `p`, and it is automatically converted to its value.)
- For `**p`, we know from above that `*p` is `p[0]`, so `**p` is `*p[0]`. `p[0]` points to `a[0]`, so `*p[0]` is `a[0]`.

In `printf(“...”, pp, *pp, **pp); }`:

- `pp` points to the first element of `p`, so the address of `p[0]` is sent to `printf`.
- In `*pp`, since `pp` points to the first element of `p`, `*pp` is that first element, `p[0]`, and `p[0]` points to `a[0]`, so the address of `a[0]` is sent to `printf`.

In `**pp`, we know from above `*pp` is `&a[0]`, so `*pp` is `*&a[0]`, which is `a[0]`.